# Why is a NumPy int not an instance of a Python int, but a NumPy float is an instance of a Python float?

Tags: python, numpy, types

Consider the following:

```
>>> import numbers
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.int_(0)
>>> isinstance(a, int)
False
>>> isinstance(a, numbers.Integral)
True
>>> b = numpy.float_(0)
>>> isinstance(b, float)
True
>>> isinstance(b, numbers.Real)
True
```

NumPy's `numpy.int_` and `numpy.float_` types are both in Python's [numeric abstract base class hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html), but it is strange to me that a `np.int_` object *is not* an instance of the built-in `int` class, while a `np.float_` object *is* an instance of the built-in `float` type.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python integers can be arbitrary length: `type(10**1000)` is still `int`, and will print out a one and then a thousand zeros on your screen if you output it.

Numpy `int64` (which is what `int_` is on my machine) are integers represented by 8 bytes (64 bits), and anything over that cannot be represented. For example, `np.int_(10)**1000` will give you a wrong answer - but quickly ;).

Thus, they are different kinds of numbers; subclassing one under the other makes as much sense as subclassing `int` under `float` would, is what I assume `numpy` people thought. It is best to keep them separate, so that no-one is confused about the fact that it would be unwise to confuse them.

The split is done because arbitrary-size integers are slow, while `numpy` tries to speed up computation by sticking to machine-friendly types.

On the other hand, floating point is the standard IEEE floating point, both in Python and in `numpy`, supported out-of-the-box by our processors.

Answer (score 1):

Because `numpy.int_()` is actually 64-bit, and `int` can have an arbitrary size, it uses about 4 extra bytes for every 2^30 worth of bits you put in. `int64` has constant size:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.int_(0)
>>> type(a)
<type 'numpy.int64'>
>>> b = 0
>>> type(b)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The type of `a = np.float_(0)` is `numpy.float64`, but it is still an instance of `float`. My question can be rephrased as "why is `numpy.float64` a subclass of `float` but `numpy.int64` is not a subclass of `int`?"

Comment: @ArtemMavrin `int` can have an arbitrary size, it uses about 4 extra bytes for every 2^30 worth of bits you put in. `int64` has constant size.