# Python type checking: int vs int64, float vs float64

Tags: python, isinstance

In Python, I want to check if certain field values in a dataframe are the correct type.
So, I've tried like this:

```
t2check = isinstance(df['T2'][0], float)
print("t2check={}  type={}".format(t2check, type(df['T2'][0])))
```

the return I got was
`t2check=True  type=<class 'numpy.float64'>`

so: on a check for "float", it returned numpy.float64, and said that was equal. OK.

HOWEVER, on a similar check for an integer value, I get this:

```
    passcheck = isinstance(df['Pass'][0], int)
    print("passcheck={}  type={}".format(passcheck, type(df['Pass'][0])))
```

When I run that, I get `passcheck=False  type=<class 'numpy.int64'>`

Here, it says the field value is NOT an "int" - but that it's a numpy.int64.

It doesn't match for me.
**Why is it loosely equating for floats, and being tight with the definition for int?**

I also tried
`passcheck64 = isinstance(df['Pass'][0], numpy.int64)`
but that returned False as well...

Comment: I suggest you to read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186804/why-is-a-numpy-int-not-an-instance-of-a-python-int-but-a-numpy-float-is-an-inst

Comment: thx. Now, since I'm actually dealing with numpy fields, I now did checks against numpy types. How to is here:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-data-type-in-numpy/